# Does Delphi 2006 work inside VirtualBox?

Tags: delphi, virtualbox, delphi-2006

I'm getting a lot of error messages, as well as slow performance. ... Is there a workaround? (I heard Delphi 2007 does not work inside VirtualBox.)

Comment: Error messages from the IDE itself, I presume?

Comment: It would help to see what error messages you have.  
"I heard Delphi 2007 does not work inside VirtualBox." And where did you have heard that? VirtualBox doesn't work like WINE where every WinAPI has to be implemented. It runs Windows itself so all WinAPIs are there.

Comment: Plus, which Windows is being run?!?

Comment: Where did you hear what? And what error messages are you getting?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. ... My guest OK is XP, and I was getting AV's with core IDE bpl's. However, I continued experimenting last night & now think the issues are/were related more to accessing a network drive and, especially, a USB flash drive. I was trying to keep source code separate from the VM. ... Thank you, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Delphi2010 inside VirtualBox. Working really nice without any problems.

Learned a lot on the follwoing site:

[link text](http://www.niccolofavari.com/virtualbox-make-windows-xp-guest-more-than-50-faster-with-these-tips)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm going to try his set up and see what differences it makes.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested W2009 and D2010 inside VirtualBox and both have work fine.

---

Neftalí -Germán Estévez-